# how to submit the form (without submit button) when DHTMLXslider change value?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, slider

I am using DHTMLXslider in a form and I want form to auto submit slider value to php file whenever slider value change. I tried using onchange and onclick event but it doesn't work.
Here is my code. Is there any solution? Please help. Thanks.

```
<form method="POST" target="content" action="here.php" id="myform">
<input class="dhtmlxSlider" skin="ball" min="10" max="20" step="1" type="text" name="slider2" id="slider" style="width:200px" value="20" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>  
<br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not clear your question. check is this ok in your application. `onChange=formname.submit();`

Comment: Sorry.Here is my code. <form method="POST" target="content" action="abc.php" id="myform">


<input class="dhtmlxSlider" skin="ball" min="10" max="20" step="0.5" type="text" name="slider" id="slider" style="width:200px" value="20" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>  <br>
</form>

Comment: I already tried onchange="this.form.submit()" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
onmouseup="this.form.submit();"
```